# UTF8 charecter shown and not shown in rows

Tags: android, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

UTF8 charecter shown and not shown in rows in mysql database.

[image: database]

in the other hand getting data  in database and showing in chrome works perfectly.

[image]

I need one of method in two solution.

1-) how to show correctly utf-8 charecter that is not shown in database

2-) It is encoded as utf-8 charecter and shown in php script but in android it is not shown in correctly as well.It is like database shown & not shown
How to decode in android.Done below method not worked

```
 String t =c.getString("columnistName");
    String name = new String(t.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    kYC.setYazarName(name);
```

It is not worked.
**Prefer solution method to shown mysql correctly**

Comment: could not found the problem...It still persist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&#...;` things are "html entities", possibly caused by not having the second argument on `json_encode($x,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`.

In order to get `&#...;` to show up in the output, you had to have run the output through `htmlentities()` a second time.

The goal should be to have utf8 characters stored in mysql, and do any escaping necessary on the `INSERT` and `SELECT` sides to make the rest of the code happy, too.

Please provide this to further diagnose what is in the table:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

What language are you writing in?  `new String` is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: thanks for answer. I get it what you told. But i solve errorr before your answer but after solution i get you right so that I accept your answer. I was using Turkish language and trying parse newspaper's columnist articles. I solve error with "html_entity_decode($yazarAdi[0], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); code"